# ROUND SQL WITH 3 DECIMAL AFTER PLACES

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to do this please

```
select round(9.100000, 3) from dual
```

Result = `9.100`

```
select round(12679.1000001, 3) from dual
```

Result = `12679.100`

Thanks

Comment: Your queries are already correct for rounding.  Then what is your question?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with `to_char` method :

```
select to_char(9.100000, '999.999') from dual 

select to_char(12679.1000001, '99999.999') from dual
```

Example with a table rather than with constant values:

```
with temp as (
    select 9.100000 as num from dual
    union
    select 12679.1000001 as num from dual
    union
    select -20.2356 as num from dual
)
select to_char(num,'99999.999')  from temp
```

Comment: How do you know the OP wants strings as output?

Comment: @GrishaWeintraub Thanks, I see it now +1 :-)

Comment: its OK but, this numbers are not constants , mean i can get any number, so is there a common technique to do this ?

Comment: @zebiridjallil You can use `to_char` with not constant values in the same way as with constant. See my edited answer.